# I'm trying to prove a formula regarding the total displacement due to the Coriolis effect of a bullet shot upwards

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, projectile

So my textbook gave me this formula

$$\frac{4v^3\Omega\cos{\varphi}}{3g^2}$$

where $v$ is the velocity of the bullet, $\Omega$ is the angular velocity of the Earth, $\varphi$ is the latitude, and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.

I know that the vertical component of the Coriolis force is $2v\Omega\cos{\varphi}$, while the time of flight of a projectile is $\frac{2v\sin{\theta}}{g}$ where $\theta$ is the angle of the projectile.

Since the bullet is shot straight up, the time of flight would be $\frac{2v}{g}$. That leaves me with,

$$\frac{4v^2\Omega\cos{\varphi}}{g}$$

It seems that I'm still missing a certain $\frac{v}{3g}$ but I somehow don't know where to get it from. Centrifugal force maybe? Although I'm not sure.

Comment: The dimension of the "texbook formula" is [length], which is not force. Are you sure you wrote the expression correctly? Your expression also has units of speed.

Comment: Yup I wrote it correctly. The textbook formula is supposed to be "the distance to the west of the point from which the bullet was fired"

Comment: *I know that the vertical component of the Coriolis force is $2v\Omega\cos{\varphi}$.* That expression has the dimensions of acceleration, not force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to obtain distance (to compare the the answer with that in the textbook) you have to take the Coriolis acceleration and compute ($t_{up}=v_0/g$)
$$d= 2\int_0^{t_{up}} dt v_x(t)$$ while
$$v_x(t)=\int_0^t a_{cor}(t') dt'$$ and
$$a_{cor}(t)=2\Omega\cos(\phi) v_y(t)$$ and finally
$$v_y(t)=v_0-gt$$.

Combining everything you will arrive at your textbook answer.

Your mistake was that you simply multiplied acceleration by time and instead of the distance got something related to the horizonthal velocity (due to Coriolis) right before hitting the ground.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much! Silly of me to forget that the coriolis acceleration would vary throughout the flight as the bullet velocity would also change.